# Powershell - Easier way to get short date for filename

Tags: date, powershell, replace

More out of curiosity as its working fine for me (I'm just beginning with Powershell) but I'm using below to obtain a short date for use in file names:

```
$shortdate = (get-date).toshortdatestring().replace("/",".")
```

Is there a built in functionality for this or is this the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-Format` argument of `get-date`:

```
get-date -format "MM.dd.yyyy"
11.20.2012
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after.  Thanks mate,  I'll be sure to check the get-help more thoroughly in future!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done very similarly to how it's done in [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
$shortdate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")
```

Your method is somewhat dependent upon localization - if you run that same code on a system where the date format doesn't use `/` as a delimiter, it breaks.